# How do I use Select with Where Like in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to select select with where having like on Laravel query builder. I'm not sure why my code below doesn't work:

```
$employee_list =  DB::table('employee')->select('last_name', 'first_name')->where('first_name','like', $search_name.'%')->orderBy('employee_id')->get();
```

Comment: Your query looks ok. To help you we need more info. Please update your question with error message (if you get one) and sample data from `employee` table and what `dd($search_name)` shows?

Comment: Need more info about the error. Is empty? Generate an error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. The code is ok and working. The view was AJAX to call the controller. I was using alert to display, Weird thing was that alert was not working, so I used console.log. I am able to see the return value of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having a problem with your ajax request. Don't forget to modify the route name to the controller which fires the query you're trying to execute.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'yourRouteNameHere',
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

plz use it i think its working

### $products = DB::table('products')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $searchterm .'%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'. $searchterm .'%')->get();

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the second parameter 'asc' or 'desc' in orderBy**

```
$employee_list =  DB::table('employee')->select('last_name', 'first_name')->where('first_name','LIKE', $search_name.'%')->orderBy('employee_id','ASC')->get();
```